# flutter debug on ios simulator not working

Tags: ios, flutter

crash when build ios,here is logs:

```
Xcode build done.                                            7.1s
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(178)] Dart Error: Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version.
[VERBOSE-2:engine.cc(176)] Could not prepare to run the isolate.
[VERBOSE-2:engine.cc(123)] Engine not prepare and launch isolate.
[VERBOSE-2:FlutterEngine.mm(294)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
Lost connection to device.
```

android is OK, is there configure wrong?

Comment: Try to run the same project from XCode rather then running it from Terminal.

Comment: Try changing the device in the Simulator settings. In my case there was no device selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I delete the bin/cache directory in Flutter installation directory, then try flutter doctor -v and try again, success!

Hope it useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it seems like sdk has been altered. delete flutter/bin/cache folder. restart the app, it will be running.